# Fetch anidados usando react

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Estoy intentando realizar dos peticiones con fetch, con la respuesta de una se cambia el estado de un componente, y usando ese estado se hace una segunda petición. El problema es que la segunda petición queda en pendiente.

```
   componentDidMount(){
    console.log()
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/tour/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(tourJson=>this.setState({ tour: tourJson}))
    .then(fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}`)
    .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
    )
```

Comment: En realidad el problema es que estás pasando la devolución de una función como parámetro en el `then` en lugar de devolver un callback, que es lo que espera `then`. Para solucionarlo bastaría con corregir tu línea donde haces el segundo `fetch` y quedaría así: `.then(() => fetch(\`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}\`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hice un comentario con la respuesta, pero me pareció interesante y apropiado para el sitio explicar bien qué sucede en este caso.

Este tipo de errores son normales cuando empezamos a concatenar *theneables*

Para empezar a explicar debemos tener claro cómo funciona una promesa, y sin irnos al nivel super técnico de cómo están construidas, debes tener en cuenta que una promesa es un valor que no se va a resolver en el instante que quieras, si no en cualquier otro momento, es decir, tal cual Javascript nos está prometiendo que nos devolverá un resultado.

Como la promesa no se va a resolver justo cuando la necesitemos en el código de ejecución, si no que lo hará cuando encuentre un espacio para hacerla, entonces la forma que tenemos para poder interactuar con ese valor que retorna la promesa es por medio del método `then` el cuál recibe como parámetro un *callback* (es una función como cualquier otra en Javascript). Dicho *callback* recibirá como parámetro el valor de la promesa una vez es resuelto, es decir:

```
const callback = (value) => { console.log(value) };
algunaTareaAsincronaQueRetornaUnaPromesa()
  .then(callback)  // <= Aquí ponemos nuestra función
```

Lo que hará esto es que cuando la tarea halla finalizado, entonces mostrará el valor en la consola. Super sencillo.

Otro asunto a tener en cuenta es que las promesas son *encadenables* o *theneables* es decir, podemos hacer tantos *then* queramos o necesitemos siempre que retornemos otra promesa dentro del *then*. Esto es muy útil y es precisamente lo que estás haciendo.

**AHORA SI TU CÓDIGO**

Si empezamos a trabajar de una forma un poco más declarativa podríamos hacer con nuestro ejemplo algo así:

```
algunaTareaAsincronaQueRetornaUnaPromesa()
  .then(console.log)  // Mostrará el valor cuando esté disponible
```

Básicamente en el fondo de como fueron programadas las promesas el está tomando esa función que le pasamos y la resuelve, un ejemplo de lo que sucede puede ser esto:

```
if (hayValorDisponible) {
  callback(valorDisponible);
}
```

Y si tenemos en cuenta que el callback que pasamos es `console.log`, entonces sería algo así:

```
if (hayValorDisponible) {
  console.log(valorDisponible);
}
```

Esto nos ayuda a identificar la fuente de tu problema. entonces entendemos que lo que sucede es esto al momento de resolver la promesa:

```
if (hayValorDisponible) {
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}`)(valorDisponible);
}
```

Lo cual obviamente es un error, ya que si te das cuenta al momento de crear un objeto a partir de `fetch` te retorna un objeto no `callable` por lo que no podrías hacer algo como esto `fetch(url)(valor)`, que es precisamente lo que sucede.

La mejor forma de solucionar tu problema es partiendo de una función que llame a al `fetch`. Quedando así tu código:

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/tour/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(tourJson => this.setState({ tour: tourJson }))
    .then(() => fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log)
);
```

Como te das cuenta cambié dos líneas de tu código, en la primera volvemos una función la llamada al fetch, y la segunda línea que cambié es cuando le haces un `console.log` a tu respuesta. Básicamente porque `response.json()` retorna otra promesa, por esa razón al momento de mostrar el log te muestra que no se ha resuelto, porque no la estás esperando.

De esa forma internamente hace esto, y tu `fetch` es ejecutado exitosamente:

```
if (hayValorDisponible) {
  (() => {
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}`)
  })(valorDisponible);
}
```

Cualquier duda o pregunta, comenta

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estás devolviendo nada en la respuesta de `.then(tourJson=>this.setState({ tour: tourJson}))`.

tienes 2 opciones, o bien devolver algo para que se ejecute la siguiente promesa o bien, y creo que esto sería un poco mejor, y es esperar a que acabe `setState` y entonces hacer la siguiente llamada, que para tu caso sería algo más eficiente.

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log()
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/tour/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(tourJson => this.setState({ tour: tourJson}, () => {
      .then(fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}`)
      .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
    }))
)
```

No obstante yo crearía un función a la que pase la ruta y me devuelva la respuesta de la petición algo más genérico que puedas reutilizar, sería algo así.

```
async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}
```

Comment: Encuentro un error con los parentesis, podría indicarme como es la forma correcta de cerrar el segundo fetch?

Comment: en tu código falta un cierre de parentesis en la linea `.then(fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ciudad/${this.state.tour[0].idciudad}`)`, al final añade ) y quítaselo a la linea de debajo